# How can I get data from first API and use that data in second API request in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await

```
const [MovieList, setMovieList] = useState([]);

const options = {
  method: 'GET',
  headers: {
    accept: 'application/json',
    Authorization: 'placeholder' // actual token redacted
  }
};

useEffect(() => {
  const TrendingMovies = async () => {
    fetch('https://api.themoviedb.org/3/trending/movie/day?language=en-US', options)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => { setMovieList(data.results.slice(0, 1)) })
  }
  const MovieDetail = async () => {
    await fetch(`https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/${MovieList[0].id}?language=en-US`, options)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(response => console.log(response))
      .catch(err => console.error(err));
  }

  TrendingMovies();
  MovieDetail();
}, [])
```

There is trendingMovie form where I am getting a detail about a movie and there is an id in that API too so I want to use that id in second API call which is `MovieDetail` but it says:

> typeError can not read id of undefined.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Add your code to the question instead of just pasting the image.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `then` and chain them together.

```
TrendingMovies().then(() => MovieDetail());
```

The second function only runs once the first one is resolved.
In general, you could use `await` as well but that is not recommended inside `useEffect`.

Alternatively, you can return the value from the 1st function and get it as a parameter in the 2nd function.

```js
function TrendingMovies(){
  return fetch(...).then((data) => data...id); // Make sure you return id
}

function MovieDetail(id){
  // Your fetch fn here
}

// You can invoke them as
TrendingMovies().then(id => MovieDetail(id));
```

Be mindful of error handling. If the first function fails it will not return an ID and the second fn will have `undefined` as a parameter instead which will result also in a failure.

Comment: You left out a very important justification of why you didn't initiate the second fetch based off **changed state** (`MovieList` is a `useState` that got modified with a `setMovieList` after the first request completed).  It's a little too hand-wavy to just say "Make sure you return id".  The original attempt relied on the resulting state change that occurred from `setMovieList`, and you didn't explain why you didn't do it that way.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the two functions you can use one function for api call use async await keyword for data fetching. By this way u can use one api's data to another api.
also take the setMovieList in the useEffect's dependency array.